# How to gather multiple remote servers' CPU utilization info?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, multiple-instances, parallel-processing

I need to test program in multiple remote servers, and at the same time need to gather the CPU utilizations information during the process.

Here use one server (10.18.6.0) as the master server

Multiple servers: (10.18.6.1)  (10.18.6.2)  (10.18.6.3)  (10.18.6.4)

Use *pssh* to control all parallel processes

So how to gather the CPU utilization info during the process?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to eyeball the loads while the installation is going on you could

`ssh 10.18.6.1 uptime`

for each host

Put it in a loop like this:

```
while :
do
  for hname in "10.18.6.1" "10.18.16.2" "10.18.16.3" "10.18.16.4"
  do
    echo $hname
    ssh $hname uptime
  done
echo
sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Tools such as [Sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html) may be configured to collect system metrics.

If you're looking for some web-based solution, you have [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) or [Collectd](https://collectd.org/), maybe even http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html. We could also mention anything SNMP-based.

Let's not forget about [Netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata): even though that one won't keep persistent histories, it can be pretty helpful keeping an eye on instantaneous resources usage.